# How to find which slider a wordpress site uses?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

is there any way of finding which slider a wordpress site uses ,I am working on a project and I want to know which slider plugin   http://www.leadingmcw.com/ uses

Comment: Look at the code and/or have a good overview about the probably thousands of sliders out there for WordPress. That should help you for the start.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, you can use the inspector to view the loaded assets which can give you some hints about the website.

Select the "Sources" tab and open up the "wp-content" folder and you will see that the theme used is called [Listify](http://themeforest.net/item/wordpress-directory-theme-listify/full_screen_preview/9602611) which you can buy from Themeforest.

The page doesn't have much info about the slider used, but it isn't a WordPress plugin because you would see in the "plugins" folder. If you search around the javascript folders, you will find a file called slider.min.js, so it is likely the theme is using a modified version of the [JQuery UI Slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/).